# Querying last.fm API with java

Tags: java, xml, last.fm

What I tried to do was use the last.fm API and track.getSimiliar to find 100 similiar songs to cher - believe. then find 10 similar songs to each of those 100 songs.

when I try to find the 10 similar songs I am using the function call inside a while loop and iterating through the collection returned. this works till the 7th call and then it errors out.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Collection;


import de.umass.lastfm.*;

public class question {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");

        String key = "6d1b1a7cbcc442e70b3bffcfb163c9a0"; // this is the key used
                                                            // in the Last.fm
                                                            // API examples
        String user = "dgupta33";   
        PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(new File("output_trackNames.txt"));
        PrintStream outFile2 = new PrintStream(new File("output_Artist.txt"));

        Collection<Track> tracks = Track.getSimilar("Cher", "Believe", key);
        int num = 1;
        for (Track track : tracks) {
            if (track.getMbid() != "" && num <= 100) {

                outFile.println(track.getName());
                outFile2.println(track.getArtist());
                num++;              

            } else if (num > 100)
                break;
        }
        outFile.close();
        outFile2.close();
    }


}
```

the error that I am getting:

```
[Fatal Error] :2025:48: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
Exception in thread "main" de.umass.lastfm.CallException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2025; columnNumber: 48; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at de.umass.lastfm.Caller.call(Caller.java:268)
    at de.umass.lastfm.Caller.call(Caller.java:189)
    at de.umass.lastfm.Track.getSimilar(Track.java:369)
    at initiate.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2025; columnNumber: 48; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at de.umass.lastfm.Caller.createResultFromInputStream(Caller.java:324)
    at de.umass.lastfm.Caller.call(Caller.java:256)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: It looks the API server returns an XML result which the client cannot parse. Might be incompatibility due to incompatible server and client versions? Make sure you use the lastest available client version.